# Matlab: Need help modelling a CO2 gas cooler using a solver

Tags: matlab, solver

I am trying do make a CO2 gas cooler model to be included in a larger model. The attached picture illustrates the problem. The red curve is CO2 being cooled down in an isobaric process. The blue line is water being heated by the CO2. The arrows indicate that it is an counter flow heat exchanger (gas cooler).

The gas cooler is split into n subparts (illustrated by dotted lines) in order to get a more accurate model, due to the T_mean approximation. A smaller figure down to the right shows one of these subparts.

Three different energy equations (`Q1`, `Qa` and `Qb`) must be satisfied. They must be equal. `c_p,b` is constant. `h`is the specific enthalpy for CO2 at a given pressure and temperature. This is found using a matlab function called REFPROP (h=refpropm('H','T','P',,'co2')).

I guess I have to use some sort of solver in order to calculate the gas cooler values from top right, where I already know T1 and T3, but I don't know how. I have never used a solver in matlab, but from what I've heard it is done by defining the equations, and which values unknown. Is this correct?

I'm rather new to Matlab, so I need to get some help in order to get started. How do I build up such a solver? How to make it work for a case like this? I guess I have to place the solver inside a for loop, for example:

```
for i=1:n  % n equals number of subparts
   do solver thing
end
```

How can the solver execution time be improved? I know that:

```
T_a,in > T_b_out
T_a,out > T_b_in
T_b,out <= 75
T_b,in >= 5
T_a,in <= 115
```

I do not know that the red line always has higher values than the blue line. If that's the case, the pressure must be increased. However, I want to do this outside the function.

Please let me know what is missing from my explanation. I know my explanation might be a bit hard to understand.

[image: Gas cooler/heat exchanger]

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your question is. Do you want to reproduce the above image? I don't really see how the temperature is dependent on the enthalpy in your formulae, so I wonder how the graph was made.

Comment: @wou: I guess that the x-axis could represent the temperature development from inlet to outlet in the heat exchanger (gas cooler) instead. I will update the image when I get to the laptop. The above graph is made by freehand drawing in Illustrator, but the resulting temperature plot should be something similar.

Comment: No what I meant was: how are the two quantities related. But from a careful re-reading I guess that the quantity called 'enthalpy' in the graph is the same as the `Q_1`, `Q_a` and `Q_b` quantities, correct? As I see it, you have a series of equations, one for each subsection and with its own linear equations. You now need to solve the entire set of equations by leveraging your knowledge of `T_2`, `T_1` and `T_3`. If those assumptions I just put here are correct, please consider adding that to the question to make it a bit clearer you are trying to solve a system of linear equations... (cont.)

Comment: One way I can think of doing this is by putting your equations in symbolic matrix equations using `T = sym('T',[rows cols])` and then using the `solve` command. However, for large sets of equations this may be very slow, so I'm guessing there is a quicker way to go about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you're correct in your assumptions. I will provide a more detailed update tomorrow morning.

Comment: @WouterKuijsters: I have updated the first post with a new illustration and changed the text. Thanks for your feedback.